# ASP.NET WebMethod for Ajax not accepting date form "dd/MM/yyyy"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, date

In one of my ASP.NET project I am requesting data using jQuery ajax request with some parameters. One of them is date parameter and the format is 'dd/MM/yyyy'

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somePath/xyzMethod",
    data: "{'param1': 'a', 'date': '31/08/2017'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async:true,// false,
    success: functions(response) { }  
});
```

In my .vb file I have the following WebMethod for above ajax call:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Shared Function xyzMethod(ByVal param1 As String, Byval date as 
DateTime)

//End Function
```

When the ajax call is made I received the following error:

```
{Message: "30/08/2017 is not a valid value for DateTime.",…}
ExceptionType
:
"System.FormatException"
Message
:
"30/08/2017 is not a valid value for DateTime."
StackTrace
:
"   at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)"
```

Comment: change that to string and cast that string value inside you method to DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

First the parameters sent to the WebMethod and the parameters of the WebMethod don't match:

> param1 - p1
>   date - Date

If you set your ajax data like:

```
data: "{'param1': 'a', 'date1': '31/08/2017'}"
```

Change your date parameter from `DateTime` to `String`, then this VB code should work:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Shared Function xyzMethod(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal date1 As String)
    Dim convertedDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date1)
    'Return what you need
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Note: if I set the date parameter of the WebMethod to `date`, I got the following error:

> Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

Comment: See my update. Did you try to change your WebMethod parameter from `DateTime` to `String`?